# How to configure Avahi network on Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: networking

How to configure Avahi network on Ubuntu 14.04 ? anyone help me . I can't access more Internet connection, access few internet Connection, See this image

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should NOT call your local domain .local because that is a reserved namespace for bonjour aka avahi aka zeroconf. Change your local domainname to localnet or something else.